# how to input python code in run time and execute it?

Tags: python

Well i want to input a python function as an input in run time and execute that part of code 'n' no of times. For example using tkinter i create a textbox where the user writes the  function and submits it , also mentioning how many times it wants to be executed. My program should be able to run that function as many times as mentioned by the user.

Ps: i did think of an alternative method where the user can write the program in a file and then i can simply execute it as python filename as a system cmd inside my python program , but i dont want it that way.

Comment: this solution may work for you. Just create a dictionary of user defined functions by using exex input() in some_dict.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6098736/2368836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `execfile()` is for.

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile

1. Create a temporary file.
2. Write the content of the textbox into the file.
3. Close.
4. Execfile.
5. Delete when done.

Comment: well performance is also a constraint here , would creating and deleting a temp file increase the time of execution ?

Comment: Yes.  Microscopically.  Try to measure it.

Answer (score 2):

Python provides number of ways to do this using function calls:
- eval()
- exec()

For your needs you should read about exec.

Comment: Just be very careful about the security -- you're basically allowing any user who has access to that input to execute any arbitrary code as the user who's executing the python program. Should be fine if it's just a single user environment, but if any part of the program needs administrative/root privileges or if that input goes to a server somewhere else to execute, you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: well basically the input function will be run over the cluster network. But for now i would limit to single system , since i am building a small prototype.  but wat kind of security issues are you taking about ?

Comment: Giving someone the ability to run in `exec` gives them pretty complete power over the machine. How would you feel if someone ran this code: `import os, os.path
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for f in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, f)
        os.remove(fullpath)
`

Comment: well its for my project .. so its more like a controlled demonstration. I am trying to create a map reduce framework

Answer (score 0):

Would IPython do?

Doc: http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/Documentation