# Can I dynamically modify (monkey patch) an existing python class method to add a decorator

Tags: python, monkeypatching

Let's say I have an existing python 2.7 class:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def foo1(self):
        return self.foo2()

    def foo2(self):
        return self.foo3()

    def foo3(self):
        return 'Hello World!'
```

Is there a way during runtime to dynamically add (monkey patch) a decorator (@testdecorator) to each of the three existing methods, foo1, foo2, and foo3?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Also might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098073/creating-a-function-object-from-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like a horrible thing to do, but it's perfectly possible. `@decorator` is just syntactic sugar; you can do it the long way:

```
TestClass.foo1 = testdecorator(TestClass.foo1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
TestClass.foo1 = testdecorator(TestClass.foo1)
```

And so on.

If you want to patch it on specific instances rather than on the class, that is doable too, although it's a little more work.