# Creating a Python Object from a String in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is not a duplicate of [creating a function object from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098073/creating-a-function-object-from-a-string) because that is a Python 2 solution with `exec` not as a function()

Trying to implement that solution in Python 3 gets this:

```
d = {}
exec("def f(x): return x")in d
print(d)
```

returns:

```
{}
```

So the question is, how do I create a function in Python 3 from an arbitrary string? (In my case read in from a YAML file, but that's a side issue.)

Comment: I don't understand what the `in d` part is trying to do.  If you just `exec` that code, you will be able to call `f(x)` in your code.  Either way, I would never recommend running arbitrary strings, this seems like an XY problem

Comment: I need the function object so I can place it in an object to be used later.  The use must be able to create an arbitrary function that uses data from the object.

Comment: @user3483203 that's part of the syntax of the `exec` keyword in Python 2 (apparently). It seems like a honkin' bad idea to me.

Comment: Right. Understand that folks don't know my application.

Moving beyond the question of whether others would do it, is it still possible to create a function object from an arbitrary string?

Comment: @RaySalemi "The user must be able to create an arbitrary function" You realize how dangerous that is, right?

Comment: Yes I do. Thanks. That's not a problem in my application.

Comment: @RaySalemi hmm I guess I'm not imaginative enough to envision a use case where that danger is warranted ;) but I trust you've done your homework on that threat vector!

Comment: It returns `{}` as it is not being called anywhere. (wrong info, ignore.)

Comment: @sP_ No, it returns `{}` because `d` is an empty dictionary. The middle line of code just checks if `None` is a member of `d`, which it is not.

Comment: @AdamSmith yes, this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`X in d` , returns True if X is found in element d.

Your exec call is defining function f in global scope.

This appears to do what you want it to:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> exec("def f(x): return x", d)
>>> d["f"]("Hello World")
'Hello World'
```

Comment: Thanks!  I see now how the `exec` has changed (and now that I understand it, improved.)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d={}
>>> exec("def f(x): return x",None,d)
>>> d['f'](2)
2
>>>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a brief explanation?